# python : Is the argument *args optional

Tags: python

We know `*args` is used to pass a variable number of arguments to a function. Now if we have a function with signature as follow

```
def myFunction(*args)
```

Is it necessary that `myFunction` is called with at least one argument?

Comment: If there only was a way to find out!

Answer (score 4):

This could easily have been tested...

```
>>> def myFunction(*args):
...     pass
... 
>>> myFunction()
>>>
```

So no, it is not necessary...

Answer (score 1):

Think of `*args` as a list of optional arguments, which it actually is. You can pass zero arguments to your function, and in this case `*args` will simply be an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

```
def myFunction(*args):
```

This means You can pass from 0 to n number of parameter.